# SQL Server Database Attach error. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When im trying to attach database get such error Does Anyone have an idea what can be problem?
[image]

[image]

Comment: so it looking for med.ldf but you have med_log.ldf, have you tried to rename? I understand that this is strange because_log.ldf is standard suffix but anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the Log file seems to be incorrect. it should be "Med_log.ldf" instead of "Med.ldf"

Answer (score 6):

On your first picture, I see the `med_log.ldf` file. On second picture you trying to attach `med.ldf`. Try to change the name of file in line 3 to `med_log.ldf`.

Answer (score 4):

Your error message states that it is looking for Med.ldf, not Med_log.ldf.

You need to change the filename in the second part of your restore command to match this filename.

Comment: Correct and **first** answer. Does no-one understand how "xx mins **ago**" works when they vote up?

Comment: @gbn. Taa. To be fair they were all very close!!

Comment: @gbn, also to be fair (a) when all votes are equal, they're shown in random order, and it is probably instinctive to vote up the first answer seen (I'm sure some do *not* look at the "n mins ago" string) and (b) after the first hour, it is impossible to tell which one came first when they are seconds or minutes apart. As soon as one person does (a) and especially after an hour has gone by, it's going to look like that was the first answer even though it was mistakenly attributed. I wouldn't get too worked up - I've given up on the dream that everyone will use the system correctly.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: I'm not, this was less than an hour, can be sorted

Comment: @gbn The key is *can* ... it's not the default, and I would guess that more than half the users of SO are not ultimately concerned with using it perfectly. I'm much more annoyed by drive-by down-voting than worrying about whether someone else got up-voted even though I answered two minutes earlier. I'm sure that in many cases it's because of the dumb random sorting and/or lack of knowledge to even look for the earliest answer. It's not a race, in my opinion.

Comment: @gbn here's a prime example that I'm not going to get worked up over. The most votes are on the newest answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065814/counting-the-rows-of-a-column-where-the-value-of-a-different-column-is-1?answertab=oldest#tab-top