# Counting the rows of a column where the value of a different column is 1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, distinct, case

I am using a `select count distinct` to count the number of records in a column. However, I only want to count the records where the value of a different column is 1.

So my table looks a bit like this:

**Name------Type**
abc---------1
def----------2
ghi----------2
jkl-----------1
mno--------1

and I want the query only to count abc, jkl and mno and thus return '3'.

I wasn't able to do this with the CASE function, because this only seems to work with conditions in the same column.

EDIT: Sorry, I should have added, I want to make a query that counts both types.
So the result should look more like:
1---3
2---2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM dbo.[table name] 
  WHERE [type] = 1;
```

If you want to return the counts by type:

```
SELECT [type], COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.[table name]
  GROUP BY [type]
  ORDER BY [type];
```

*You should avoid using keywords like type as column names - you can avoid a lot of square brackets if you use a more specific, non-reserved word.*

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll want (assuming that you wouldn't want to count ('abc',1) twice if it is in your table twice):

```
select count(distinct name) 
  from mytable
 where type = 1
```

EDIT: for getting all types

```
select type, count(distinct name)
  from mytable
 group by type
 order by type
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I forgot to mention that I want to make a query that counts both types. So the result should look more like: 1---3 2---2

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH MyTable (Name, [Type]) AS
(
SELECT 'abc', 1
UNION
SELECT 'def', 2
UNION
SELECT 'ghi', 2
UNION
SELECT 'jkl', 1
UNION
SELECT 'mno', 1
) 
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT Name)
FROM MyTable
WHERE [Type] = 1
```

Comment: a little tip: add semicolon before WITH :)

Answer (score 1):

select count(1) from tbl where type = 1